# completely confused with archive.php, category.php

Tags: categories

I can't get any 'category' loops to load.

Here is my work flow.

I create a page called category.php and placed the following code (exactly like this):

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: Category
 */

if (!defined('ABSPATH'))
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
get_header();
?>

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

<div class="entry-content">

<?php the_content(); ?>

<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I then created a page called 'Category' in the WP Admin and then selected the template for category.php and nothing - zero.

Why wouldn't this load posts that belong to the relevant category?

Thanks for all help with this...

Answer (score 1):

You don't assign category templates to pages. They are templates that will be used *automatically* when you view a category.

Read the [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) documentation. You're using WordPress completely wrong. You don't create pages for archives, they exist automatically.

Comment: I've deleted the page I made within WordPress admin but left exactly the same php page as above - cleared cache, cookies - refreshed - and still nothing....thanks for the help but can you think of anything else that might be preventing the loop of these categorized posts?

Comment: Should my functions.php have a call to the archive or category.php pages?

Comment: What page on the front end are you actually viewing? Go to Posts > Categories and click the view link. And make sure the category has posts. And delete the Template Name comment at the top, just to be safe. And no, your functions file should not be 'calling' your template files.

Answer (score -1):

I know what went wrong: I had added categories to my pages (with functions.php code). Now I have to connect the categories to display with the archive template. I don't have an opportunity to test my theory but I'm sure it is that

Comment: You don't have to 'connect' anything. Categories will automatically use a template based on the theme hierarchy. For the love of god please read the documentation.